# Python Debug Fail - execution ends

Tags: python, visual-studio, unit-testing, debugging

I'm debugging Python with Visual Studio 2015 (Python Tools extension).

I'm very new to Python and strangely when i debug the bellow code, it runs to line 18, then line 19, then line 18 again where it exits unceremoniously. Doesn't hit my catch block, doesn't hit line 20 or 21.  No error message.  Anyone know what might be causing this?

The unit test is testing a common google api functionality found on Git Hub [here](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-dfa-reporting-samples/blob/master/python/v2_8/dfareporting_utils.py).

My Code:

```
import unittest
import sys
import os
import exceptions
from _multiprocessing import flags


sys.path.insert(0, "C:\Users\Jamie.Marshall\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\GetDCMPlalyStationData\DCMPSDataQuery")

try:
    from dfareporting_utils import get_arguments
except ImportError:
    print(ImportError.message)
    print('No Import')


try:
#Line18 
    class Test_dfareporting_utility_test(unittest.TestCase):   
#Line19                                                 
        def test_A(self):                           
            flags = get_arguments(sys.argv, __doc__, parents=[argparser])
            self.assertEqual(flags[0], "")

except Exception as ex:
    print(ex.message)
    print(ex.source)  

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        unittest.main()
```

Comment: When a class is initialized, only the signature lines and the code of the methods inside are executed. The code in the methods is executed only when the methods are called. Your `try` around the class will have no effect unless an error is raised on the `class` or the `def` line.

Comment: How about the result remove try module? What Klaus said should be a great possibility "Your try around the class will have no effect unless an error is raised on the class or the def line."

Comment: Klaus is right.  I didn't understand the run order of the script.  @Klaus D can you post as an answer so i can mark answered?  Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a class is initialized, only the signature lines of the class, the code at the top level of the class and signature lines the methods inside are executed. The code in the methods is executed only when the methods are called. An example:

```
E class MyClass:
|
E     my_class_attribute = 1
|
E     def my_method(self, a):
N         b = a + 1
N         return b

E = excuted; N = not executed
```

Your try around the class will have no effect unless an error is raised on the class or the def line.

At the result your try around the class will have no effect unless an error is raised in one of that lines.

To catch an exception in a test put the `try` / `except` inside the method. But you should actually have a defined state in your test and the error should be expected or not present, so it might be the best to expect an error and test for it with `with self.assertRaises(YourErrorType):`